# Highlighting the winning move in connect 4

Tags: python, numpy

```py
def winning_move(board, piece):
    # Check horizontal locations for win
    for c in range(COLUMN_COUNT-3):
        for r in range(ROW_COUNT):
            if board[r][c] == piece and board[r][c+1] == piece and board[r][c+2] == piece and board[r][c+3] == piece:
                return True

    # Check vertical locations for win
    for c in range(COLUMN_COUNT):
        for r in range(ROW_COUNT-3):
            if board[r][c] == piece and board[r+1][c] == piece and board[r+2][c] == piece and board[r+3][c] == piece:
                return True

    # Check positively sloped diaganols
    for c in range(COLUMN_COUNT-3):
        for r in range(ROW_COUNT-3):
            if board[r][c] == piece and board[r+1][c+1] == piece and board[r+2][c+2] == piece and board[r+3][c+3] == piece:
                return True

    # Check negatively sloped diaganols
    for c in range(COLUMN_COUNT-3):
        for r in range(3, ROW_COUNT):
            if board[r][c] == piece and board[r-1][c+1] == piece and board[r-2][c+2] == piece and board[r-3][c+3] == piece:
                return True
```

I made a connect 4 game using python but i want to draw a line or a circle showing the 4 counter matched in a row I am using python and used pygame as a library and don't mind using turtle. It is stored as a numpy array

Comment: `numpy` seems like overkill for representing a small array that you aren't doing matrix operations on.

Comment: I just found it easier to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to draw a line through the winning pieces, the `winning_move` has to return the start and end of the line

There are just 4 rows, 4 columns and 2 diagonals:

```py
def winning_move(board, piece):
    # Check horizontal locations for win
    for r in range(ROW_COUNT):
        if board[r][0] == piece and board[r][1] == piece and board[r][2] == piece and board[r][3] == piece:
            return (r, 0), (r, 3)

    # Check vertical locations for win
    for c in range(COLUMN_COUNT):
        if board[0][c] == piece and board[1][c] == piece and board[2][c] == piece and board[3][c] == piece:
            return (0, c), (3, c)

    # Check positively sloped diaganols
    if board[0][0] == piece and board[1][1] == piece and board[2][2] == piece and board[3][3] == piece:
        return (0, 0), (3, 3)

    # Check negatively sloped diaganols
    if board[0][3] == piece and board[1][2] == piece and board[2][1] == piece and board[3][0] == piece:
        return (0, 3), (3, 0)

    return None, None
```

A more general approach for connect N is

```py
def winning_move(board, piece, N=4):
   
    for i in range(N):
        if all(board[i][j] == piece for j in N):
            return (i, 0), (i, N-1)
        if all(board[j][i] == piece for j in N):
            return (0, i), (N-1, i)

    if all(board[i][i] == piece for i in N):
        return (0, 0), (N-1, N-1)
    if all(board[i][N-1-i] == piece for i in N):
        return (0, N-1), (N-1, 0)

    return None, None
```

Invoke the function and get the start and end pint of the line:

```py
start, end = winning_move(boar, pice):
if start and end:
   print(start, end)
  
   # draw line from start to end
   # [...]
```

Comment: The check win function works but I want a line drawn to show the 4 in a row

Comment: I tried to draw jus a simple line from board[r][c] but it did not work

Comment: def winningpos(board, piece):
    # Check horizontal locations for win
    for c in range(COLUMNS - 3):
        for r in range(ROWS):
            if board[r][c] == piece and board[r][c + 1] == piece and board[r][c + 2] == piece and board[r][
                c + 3] == piece:
                pygame.draw.line(screen, WHITE, board[r][c] , board[r][c+3] , 20)
                return True

Comment: I tired that its just for the horizontal win though

Comment: I have added some suggestions to the answer